# Problems When Editing UITableView Cells (Swift)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I thought I knew how to remove a cell from a tableview, I had done it before, but recently it didn't go so well.

In a previous iOS app I built, I used a UITableView to display items. The results looked like this:

[image: Image #1]

So far so good. To remove the cell from the tableview, I used the `commit editingStyle` function which would let me swipe on the cell and a red "Delete" button would appear:

[image: Image #2]

And this is just how I wanted it. And now I was making a new app which would also make use of the tableview and I was wanting to implement this swipe to delete feature and have it work the same way as before. So I added the `commit editingStyle` function and wrote some code to remove the item in the array that holds my cell's data and then some code to remove the cell itself. But when I ran the app, I got this:

[image: Image #3]

My cell had a red circle with a line through it. Tapping the circle showed the desired delete button, but this is not how I wanted the app to work. I wanted to swipe to delete like I had before. Well, I assumed I must have done something differently this time, so I started researching online to find how to it the right way. But every solution I found produced the same results. I went through about two dozen webpages before finally giving up. I decided to open up my other project and just pull the code from there as I knew that code was tried and true. So I did that, and I got the same results! Here's my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
        Variables.numbers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

So I have two different apps running essentially the same code, but they both produce two entirely different results. What's the deal here? Did I forget something?

OK, so I had enough. I decided to abandon the swipe to delete idea altogether, all my work and research still didn't produce the results I wanted. That circle was annoying and in the way, I didn't want it there. I was going to have to do something different. So I completely removed the `commit editingStyle` function and any code that had to do with it and ran my app. And to my horror, that little red circle was STILL there!!! I tried everything I knew to remove that little red circle, but it was STILL there!!! So, I left the project alone for about a week or two, somewhat distraught and completely unsure what to do. When I came back, that little red circle was STILL there (no surprise there). I want to get this project finished but I am completely unsure what to do.

Does anyone have any idea on what I can do to remove that little red circle and implement swipe to delete as I originally planned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IB or in your code

```
     tableView.isEditing = true
```

uncheck or remove it.

```
    tableView.isEditing = false
```